# Browser lock: Looking for solutions

Tags: web

I'm making an online exam using PHP and I was wondering if there is a way for me to lock the user's PC onto the browser only. The system will not allow the PC to load and/or open other apps/tabs while the exam is running or should prompt if the system detects that you left the page.

Comment: How would you feel if any other website was able to do that to you?

Comment: Thank you for you wonderful question Jonathon Reinhart. But I was asking a question and you did not seem to read it comprehensively. So to level with your understanding, and you may answer yes or no depending on your knowledge, I have seen testing websites do it. So have you? Thank you.